# Fixed "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)" but still getting error

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ocr, opencv3.0

Im learning opencv and having a problem while running 3 blocks of code. I tried to fix it but doesn't work at all. The other solutions states the error at contours variable and i changed it with the corrected one but still unable to run this piece of code. Can anyone help me out?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('images/numbers.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#cv2.imshow("image", image)
#cv2.imshow("gray", gray)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

# Blur image then find edges using Canny 
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
#cv2.imshow("blurred", blurred)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 30, 150)
#cv2.imshow("edged", edged)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

# Fint Contours
# _, contours,_ = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
_, contours,_ = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#Sort out contours left to right by using their x cordinates
contours = sorted(contours, key = x_cord_contour, reverse = False)

# Create empty array to store entire number
full_number = []

# loop over the contours
for c in contours:
    # compute the bounding box for the rectangle
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)    

    #cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
    #cv2.imshow("Contours", image)

    if w >= 5 and h >= 25:
        roi = blurred[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        ret, roi = cv2.threshold(roi, 127, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
        squared = makeSquare(roi)
        final = resize_to_pixel(20, squared)
        cv2.imshow("final", final)
        final_array = final.reshape((1,400))
        final_array = final_array.astype(np.float32)
        ret, result, neighbours, dist = knn.findNearest(test, k=5)
        number = str(int(float(result[0])))
        full_number.append(number)
        # draw a rectangle around the digit, the show what the
        # digit was classified as
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(image, number, (x , y + 155),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 2, (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow("image", image)
        cv2.waitKey(0) 

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print ("The number is: " + ''.join(full_number))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-97be138d1b62> in <module>
     19 # Fint Contours
     20 # _, contours,_ = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
---> 21 _, contours,_ = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     22 
     23 #Sort out contours left to right by using their x cordinates

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: The documentation says its `contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(...)`

Comment: As far as I can see, the error message is quite precise: `findContours` does only return two variables, but you ask for three. When I look at the [OpenCV doc](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0), it states usage like `contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(...)`

Comment: @magnus i tried this already but still not able to figure out the problem

Answer (score 1):

Different versions of openCV handle the countours differently. 
To be safe, use the following code instead which should work across versions:

```
try:
    _, contours,_ = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
except ValueError:    
    contours ,_ = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Alternatively, you can also use the helper library imutils:

```
contours = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
```

Comment: I added that try catch exception and got this error ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-4366866e8385> in <module>
     32 
     33 #Sort out contours left to right by using their x cordinates
---> 34 contours = sorted(contours, key = x_cord_contour, reverse = False)
     35 
     36 # Create empty array to store entire number

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Comment: I tried the 2nd one @peter it throws this error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'"
At 
"---> 35 contours = sorted(contours, key = x_cord_contour, reverse = False)"

Comment: How does the `x_cord_contour` function look like?

Comment: See this 
def x_cord_contour(contour):
    # This function take a contour from findContours
    # it then outputs the x centroid coordinates
    
    if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 10:
        M = cv2.moments(contour)
        return (int(M['m10']/M['m00']))

Comment: whole code is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yxk_NTUwjcv90UnwWfGPrSqaZtEfu2me/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This function returns None when cv2.contourArea(contour) <= 10. You are trying to sort your contours using this function, but you can't sort None values.

Comment: Alright then what will be the final code looks like?

Comment: I don't know what your code will look like. I don't know what it is supposed to do. 
Again, open a new question if you have new problems. But try to fix it yourself first. I gave you a hint on what's wrong already.